# Paste Pose Flipped Completely Moves Character

Tags: animation

So I'm trying to start a walk cycle but every time I do Paste Pose Flipped it just moves the character away from his starting position instead of just flipping it. I've tried seeing if keyframes affect the results, I've messed around with the transform panel on the right hand side to see if it'd stop but none of it has. There's two pictures below showing what I'm talking about.[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file (the armature only): https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the right bones to make a proper pose flip. Blender has no way to know what is your character's local space, it only knows the armature space and the individual bones' spaces. If you flip the entire armature, it will be done from the armature space, hence the current result.

If your rig is made with this kind of problematics in mind (which is a standard), it should at least have a `root` bone on the ground, parent of the entire rig. Maybe even an extra `offset` bone between the root and the rest. And only below these in the hierarchy should there be the beginning of your spine and all the rest of your bones:

[image]

If so, you should be able to select the bones of your characters without the root (and offset) and flip the pose on only that:

[image]

It works because the bones taking care of the character's position in the scene are either the root or offset bones, which you left untouched when flipping the pose, so the pose gets flipped relative to their space.

If you don't have any of these root/offset bones, then you need to flip from the space of whatever bone does your rig's position in the scene. I.E in this situation:

[image]

Select the bones of your characters without whatever is the positioning bone of your hierarchy (`spine` in my case), and flip on that selection:

[image]

It's not perfect because you do miss part of the pose from the `spine` bone, so you will have to flip it another way.
One of which is the Copy Global Transforms addon shipped with Blender.

Enable it under Edit menu > Preferences > Addons.

In the sidebar, set your armature name and the bone child of your positioning bone, select the positioning bone, hit Copy, then Mirrored.

[image]

If you do have a root/offset bone but didn't use it for positioning, you can fix this with the same addon. Remove all objects of the Mirror Options sub-panel, copy the global pose of all but root/offset bones with that same addon, reset the spine bone location with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, use the root/offset bone to position, and select all but root/offset bones and hit the Paste button.